# Problem with running urg_node with UST 20lx

Tags: ros, urg-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried running urg_node using command **rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:="192.168.0.10"**, but it gives an error **std::length_error what() : basic_string::_S_create** and stops. What does this error mean and how to resolve this. Thanks for the help in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261367/problem-with-running-urg_node-with-ust-20lx/) by [Sableye96](https://answers.ros.org/users/30314/sableye96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-05-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I ran into the same problem, and I believe this is a bug in a new feature of urg_node (see my post on github: [link text](https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node/issues/30))

A temporary fix is to comment line number 466 in the file src/urg_node_driver.cpp:

```
// Before starting, update the status
updateStatus();
```

Then just run catkin_make again, and it should work.

---

Originally posted by [tpra](https://answers.ros.org/users/30448/tpra/) with karma: 26 on 2017-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sableye96](https://answers.ros.org/users/30314/sableye96/) on 2017-05-19**:
Thanks. It worked.

**Comment by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) on 2017-05-24**:
This is great, thanks.